# How is Windows 10 still checking my disks at boot when I have deleted all the chkdsk exe files?

Tags: windows-10, boot, chkdsk, sfc

#### Background

I have a Windows 10 Pro (20H2) computer that will always begin a chkdsk on my E: drive on boot. The E: drive is an 11TB volume created with Window's "Manage Storage Space" tool.

This disk check never completes, it will sit in stage 2 for a week at 100%. It actually doesn't need a disk check.

#### Issue

For some unknown reason, while any plugged in keyboard works fine at the BIOS or Windows recovery menus, it will disconnect right when Windows is giving me 10 seconds to "Press any key to cancel disk check", so I can not ever get pass it.

If I was able to get past it, I would use a hex editor to clear the dirty bit on the drive.

#### Attempt to solve my Issue

I have also found the command `chkntfs /x E:` doesn't stop the disk check either. This seems to do nothing as it will still start the check disk during boot.

I also made sure to perform a `sfc /scannow` repair of Windows' core files to make sure everything was fine.

Next, using the Windows Recovery Command Line I renamed the following system32 files on *both* the C: and the D: (recovery) drives in order to prevent the disk check from starting:

```
ren chkdsk.exe _chkdsk.exe.bak
ren chkntfs.exe _chkntfs.exe.bak
ren sfc.exe _sfc.exe.bak
```

And after many restarts and Window's "automatic repair" attempts, I can confirm that those files are still renamed without any fixes by windows to replace those files. Which is what I was hoping for.

### Question

Even with my above sabotage the Windows boot automatic disk check still starts and runs normally even though I renamed those core files.

My question is how is this possible? What files might I be missing to prevent this boot disk check from starting?

Comment: Seems like this whole thing is really an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319): You really just want it to skip the disk check for one volume, right? Seems like there are multiple ways to do this as explained on [this blog post](https://www.top-password.com/blog/stop-check-disk-chkdsk-from-running-at-startup/).

Comment: Thanks for that link and the engagement. I have updated my question to mention that I have already tried the `chkntfs /x E` method and found that it was ignored by windows on boot.